# Why a C file name can be saved in a variable just right after writing a bash script?

Tags: bash

In today's class, we were asked to write a script that runs a C file through the preprocessor and save the result into another file, with the following conditions:

- The C file name will be saved in the variable `$NAMEFILE`
- The output should be saved in the file `NAME`

One my classmates fastly wrote the following code as the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
gcc -E -o NAME $NAMEFILE
```

I understand all of the code above, except the last part where the variable `$NAMEFILE` is written, it seems tricky, why can you simply store the C file name in that variable without even declaring it? the GCC manual doesn't seem to explain that, so I just want to get the logics behind this.

Comment: Environment variable... You might want to have a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495163) which explains them nicely.

Comment: I think there is some confusion. The variable `$NAMEFILE` is _not_ created (“written”) by the script — it must exist _before_ the script is executed. You should clarify what your professor’s instructions were, as they are currently (as you explained them) able to be read two different ways. If you are reading them correctly, your classmate failed. If you are misunderstanding them, your classmate succeeded.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GCC or any preprocessor, the script is run by your shell, which is bash. You will want to read its documentation to learn about environment variables and how to work with them.

Comment: @Aconcagua Are you trying to argue my two points against me? All I said is there are (at least) two contradictory ways of viewing the instructions — instructions we only get in a form that has been filtered through the OP’s understanding. The script OP’s classmate wrote simply _will not work **unless**_ `$NAMEFILE` is an environment variable that exists before the script is run.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Oh, it's getting clear to me that I misinterpreted your wording myself, as *'accepting environment variables is objectively incorrect reading of the task'* (*'if (any) one reads correctly...'*) instead of *'depending on question author's view being correct or not mate fails or not'*)... The fine grained details of the language that can turn into pitfalls for the non-native English speakers...

Comment: Better quote `"$NAMEFILE"`, if you do not know anything about the contents.

Comment: Jack of all languages, master of none, yet we play games with every single one — Abraham Lincoln.

Comment: Except for running the C compiler (`gcc`), the C language is not involved in the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the feedback provided in comment section of my post, the `$NAMEFILE` variable was a environment variable. I was suggested to read the docs related to environment variables, which I will in the following hours.

My problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating gcc operation / features with the behavior of a shell. The gcc manual would not say anything about "storing the filename in a variable" because that's part or the environment where gcc would be run.

in windows, it would look like this:

```
gcc -E -o NAME %FILENAME%
```

You're not going to find any explanation of that in the gcc manual.

The shell (bash) is like "the windows explorer". It's what you use to give the computer (OS) instructions. instead of clicking folders you do `cd folder` and instead of "double click" you type "./foo/command" or just "gcc".

So just keep that in mind and you'll be fine.